# Several Image Inputs to same ResNet Resulting in Unmatched Inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, input, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build a network where ResNet does feature detection seperately on three input images. After feature detection the three parallel branches get combined with dense layers. An error gets thrown when trying to give the model some input.

```
#basis model

in1 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='base_image')
in2 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image1')
in3 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image2')

ResNet = ResNet50(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
)
ResNet.trainable = False

out1 = ResNet(in1)
out2 = ResNet(in2)
out3 = ResNet(in3)

basis1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out1)
basis1 = Dropout(0.7)(basis1)
basis1 = Flatten()(basis1)

basis2 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out2)
basis2 = Dropout(0.7)(basis2)
basis2 = Flatten()(basis2)

basis3 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out3)
basis3 = Dropout(0.7)(basis3)
basis3 = Flatten()(basis3)


#own model
concat = Concatenate()([basis1, basis2, basis3])
dense_1 = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(concat)
dense_2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(dense_1)
output = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(dense_2)

my_model = Model(inputs = [in1, in2, in3], outputs=output)
```

Here is what the model looks like:
[image: the model produced]

The images array (definitely) returns an image with the shape (224, 224, 3)

```
testX = [
    [images[0], images[1], images[2]],
    [images[3], images[4], images[5]],
    [images[6], images[7], images[8]]
]

testY = [
    [1.0],
    [0.0],
    [1.0]
]


my_model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
my_model.fit(testX, y=testY, epochs = 5,  verbose=2)
```

Results in the following error in fit():

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224
  y sizes: 1, 1, 1
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

It seems like the first sub-arrays get ignored by this method? I've been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: you have 9 images but only 3 ground truth, this is your problem; if every row is 3 channel image if so concatenate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `model.fit()`, in my experience it is always better to have a single input, not a list. Later, manually index the input tensor to get individual images. In your case, the input shape would then be `(Batch Size, 3, 224, 224, 3)`.

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(3, 224, 224, 3), name='images')

ResNet = ResNet50(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
)
ResNet.trainable = False

out1 = ResNet(inputs[:, 0])
out2 = ResNet(inputs[:, 1])
out3 = ResNet(inputs[:, 2])

...

my_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
```

Furthermore, it's always better to construct the input and output arrays using numpy instead of leaving them as python lists, to have finer control over the pipeline:

```py
testX = np.stack([
    np.stack([images[0], images[1], images[2]], axis=0),
    np.stack([images[3], images[4], images[5]], axis=0),
    np.stack([images[6], images[7], images[8]], axis=0)
], axis=0) # Shape: (3, 3, 224, 224, 3)

testY = np.stack([1.0, 0.0, 1.0], axis=0)[:, None] # Shape: (3, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, got it to work. But are you sure, that it's `out1 = ResNet(inputs[:, 0])` and not `out1 = ResNet(inputs[0, :])` ? Since I would want one image per ResNet and the dimensions of the input are the following: (imageNr, pixels_height, pixels_width, RGB)

Comment: My bad, there are 3 three-image sequences in a batch, and the shape is `(batch, 3, height, width, RGB)`. The indexing remains the same, but I've fixed the shape comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have

```
ResNet1 = ResNet50(include_top=False,  weights="imagenet",  input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
ResNet2 = ResNet50(include_top=False,  weights="imagenet",  input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
ResNet3 = ResNet50(include_top=False,  weights="imagenet",  input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
out1 = ResNet1(in1)
out2 = ResNet2(in2)
out3 = ResNet3(in3)
basis1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out1) # this make a vector so you don't need flatten layer                                 
basis1 = Dropout(0.7)(basis1)
basis2 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out2) # this make a vector so you don't need flatten layer                                 
basis2 = Dropout(0.7)(basis2)
basis3 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(out3) # this make a vector so you don't need flatten layer                                 
basis3 = Dropout(0.7)(basis3)
concat = Concatenate()([basis1, basis2, basis3])
dense_1 = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(concat) # I would reduce nodes t0 256
# I would add a dropout layer here Dropout(.3)
dense_2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(dense_1)# I would reduce nodes to 32
output = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(dense_2)
```

If you look at your model plot all inputs were going into a single Resnet model.
Also since you are using binary_crossentropy I think your label must be just a single 1 or a 0.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Although, it is not possible to instantiate ResNet several times because when compiling the model, an error is thrown (several layers have the same given name). Since layer names are not nameable, this is a dead end. The approach of the other answer worked but I will incorporate your tip about the Dropout layer.
Thank you :)

Comment: Oh forgot that would be a problem